# ERROR: localhost redirected you too many times

Tags: php

Hi I'm a new student and starting to learn coding/programming specially on PHP. I tried learning some code and I have encountered this problem.

**This page isn’t working**

*localhost redirected you too many times.*
Try clearing your cookies.
**ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**

and this is my code:

```
session_start();

include('_includes/config.php');
include('_includes/db.php');

    if(isset($_POST['register'])){
        $_SESSION['uname'] = $_POST['uname'];
        $_SESSION['fname'] = $_POST['fname'];
        $_SESSION['lname'] = $_POST['lname'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
        $_SESSION['address'] = $_POST['address'];
        $_SESSION['postal'] = $_POST['postal'];
        $_SESSION['pass'] = $_POST['pass'];
        $_SESSION['con-pass'] = $_POST['con-pass'];
    }

    if(strlen($_POST['uname'])<3){
        header("Location:register.php?err=" . urlencode("The username must be at least 3 characters long"));
        die();
    }
```

I really don't know what to do I have encountered some errors in php but I haven't encountered this kind of error PLEASE HELP and PLEASE ENLIGHTEN me on what I have done wrong.

Comment: You enter the `if` every time and so you are always being redirected.

Comment: Didn't test but this may fix your problem. Change `if(strlen($_POST['uname'])<3)` to `if(isset($_POST['uname']) && strlen($_POST['uname'])<3)` for disabling repeated redirections.

Comment: Any suggestions on what should I do? Sorry to bother Im very new to everything this is my first time.

Comment: The code work! thank you very much! Im sure writing this in my note!

Comment: is this codes in `register.php` file ?

Comment: Yes the code is for register.php,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check if user request to register too than redirect, update code like below :

```
session_start();

include('_includes/config.php');
include('_includes/db.php');

    if(isset($_POST['register'])){
        $_SESSION['uname'] = $_POST['uname'];
        $_SESSION['fname'] = $_POST['fname'];
        $_SESSION['lname'] = $_POST['lname'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
        $_SESSION['address'] = $_POST['address'];
        $_SESSION['postal'] = $_POST['postal'];
        $_SESSION['pass'] = $_POST['pass'];
        $_SESSION['con-pass'] = $_POST['con-pass'];
    }

    if(strlen($_POST['uname'])<3 && isset($_POST['register'])){ // add && isset($_POST['register'])
        header("Location:register.php?err=" . urlencode("The username must be at least 3 characters long"));
        die();
    }
```

**Note:** at all i'm suggest you don't redirect user to show error message if codes in some file! you can store error message in vars and check if error var is not empty echo it!

```
session_start();

include('_includes/config.php');
include('_includes/db.php');
$error = ''; //add this var
    if(isset($_POST['register'])){
        $_SESSION['uname'] = $_POST['uname'];
        $_SESSION['fname'] = $_POST['fname'];
        $_SESSION['lname'] = $_POST['lname'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
        $_SESSION['address'] = $_POST['address'];
        $_SESSION['postal'] = $_POST['postal'];
        $_SESSION['pass'] = $_POST['pass'];
        $_SESSION['con-pass'] = $_POST['con-pass'];
    }

    if(strlen($_POST['uname'])<3 && isset($_POST['register'])){ // add && isset($_POST['register'])
        /*header("Location:register.php?err=" . urlencode("The username must be at least 3 characters long"));
        die();*/
        $error = 'this is error message';
    }
//add below code anywhere you want show error
if($error){
    echo $error;
}
```

Comment: works like a charm sir, Thank you very much for sharing your knowledge to a beginner like me.

Comment: @missNobody your welcome, if this answer did help you , please check the answer as true answer (below votes)

Comment: Done! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

i have been facing the same problem on my ruby on rails project
as i got redirected to the localhost too many times i got this (http status code 302) error.

it is because we are trying to redirect the localhost too many times

solution:
try to clear cookies on settings and then try again

try this page:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/127001-redirected-you-too-many-times

it'll help you move forward